# How to see "fuller" log in tortoise git?

Tags: tortoisegit

I am looking for the equivalent of `git log --pretty=fuller` in Tortoise git. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html for example consistently just says "date" while there are two dates -- and Tortoise Git actually allows you to alter one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the context menu on the columns (as in Windows Explorer) and select the columns you want to see (or change the order or the sizes).